# HowTo access Samba Share over VPN Tunnel?

Tags: openvpn

I don't know how to access a Samba share running on a Ubuntu 10.04
server through OpenVPN 2.1.0.

I've installed & configured OpenVPN and everything works. The server
end of the tunnel has the IP of 10.8.0.1. When I connect from XP (over
our local network) I'm given the IP of 10.8.0.6. I can ping and trace
route from both ends of the tunnel.

Now, I'm lost...how to access the Samba share from XP and from OS X?

Answer (score 7):

Probably you need to allow access to your samba server from the ip class of your vpn. You need to find (or insert) the following line in your /etc/samba/smb.conf file

```
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 10.8.0.0/24
```

Don't forget to add every ip class that should have access to the shares.

Then reload your samba server

```
sudo service smbd reload
sudo service nmbd reload
```