# Virtual Lan on the Cloud -- Help Confirm my understanding?

Tags: openvpn, cifs, bridge, virtualization, network-protocols

*[Note: Tried to post this over at ServerFault, but I don't have enough 'points' for
 more than one link.  Powers that be, move this question over there.]*

Please give this a quick read and let me know if I'm missing something before I start trying to make this work.  I'm not a systems admin professional, and I'd hate to end up banging my head into the wall if I can avoid it.

Goals:

- Create a 'road-warrior' capable star shaped virtual LAN for consultants who spend the majority of their time on client sites, and who's firm has no physical network or servers.
- Enable CIFS access to a cloud-server based installation of Alfresco
- Allow Eventual implementation of some form of single-sign-on ( OpenLDAP server ) access to Alfresco and other server applications implemented in the future

Given:

- All Servers will live in the public internet cloud (Rackspace Cloud Servers)
- OpenVPN Server will be a Linux disto, probably Ubuntu 9.x, installed on same server as Alfresco (at least to start)
- Staff will access server applications and resources from client sites, hotels, trains, planes, coffee shops or their homes over various ISP, using their company laptops or personal home desktops.

Based on my Research thus far, to accomplish this, I'll need:

- OpenVPN with Bridging Enabled to create a star shaped "virtual" LAN
  http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html
- A Road Warrior Network Configuration, as described in this Shorewall article (lower down the page)
  http://www.shorewall.net/OPENVPN.html
- Configure bridge addressesing (probably DHCP)
  http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq.html#bridge-addressing
- Configure CIFS / Samba to accept VPN IP address
  [HowTo access Samba Share over VPN Tunnel?](https://serverfault.com/questions/137933/howto-access-samba-share-over-vpn-tunnel)
- Set up Client software, with keys configured for access (potentially through a OpenVPN-Sa client portal) http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as/221-installation-overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds perfectly fine to me =)